# Attribute References in Python

Tags: python, oop

I do Java programming and recently started learning Python via the official documentation. 
I see that we can dynamically add data attributes to an instance object unlike in Java:

```
class House:
  pass

my_house = House()
my_house.number = 40
my_house.rooms = 8
my_house.garden = 1
```

My question is, in what situations is this feature used? What are the advantages and disadvantages compared to the way it is done in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can also be used when dynamically creating classes; see for instance this tutorial:

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html?page=1

or this one on Mix-ins, a programming technique that uses this capability to provide better encapsulation and modularity to object oriented code:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4540

The first tutorial uses `setattr(classname, "propertyname", value)` instead of the `classname.property = value` syntax, but they are the same.

Comment: There are *so* many better ways of fulfilling the needs of the asker in that thread...

Comment: Yes; it was my intention to post a factual answer quickly and edit with a more useful one. The tutorial is better, but I'm still looking for a clear practical example of the exact syntax he's asking about.

Comment: personal experience in using that sort of syntax would do fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not often done from outside of the class unless the object is being used as a bucket of sorts. It's done an awful lot inside `__init__()` of course, to provide values to attributes that will be used elsewhere.

Oh, and [speaking of Java...](http://www.archive.org/details/SeanKellyRecoveryfromAddiction)

Comment: That was a very useful video and a bit funny too!